# rains vs will rain in a condition

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

I've been wondering what is a more proper form to ask:

1) Will you go to the concert if it rains?

2) Will you go to the concert if it will rain?

As in would you still be willing to the concert if it rained?

Comment: What do you think Victor? Have you done any research yourself?

Comment: For me rains sounds much much better since I am just speculating -- what if? and not really predicting what's going to happen.

Comment: You are right. It's a good idea, if you can, to include your own conclusion when you ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1 is perfectly correct. In most contexts, we prefer to mark the future with "will," but doing so in some contexts is unidiomatic or flat-out wrong. Strictly speaking, the present and future tenses are identical in English. "Tomorrow, I fly to Europe" sounds a little aggressive but is otherwise unremarkable.

#2 is objectively incorrect. "Will" is generally forbidden in a subordinate clause introduced by "if" or a conjunction that indicates time: when, after, until, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to use the **open future condition** which means that the first sentence is correct.

Answer (score -3):

In my opinion, the first sentence is correct. The concert will happen sometimes in the future. So this is already a future incident. There is no need to say, the next incident in the future. As per the rule if the first one is in future tense then the second one should be in the simple past tense.